# Hiding the left admin menu?

Tags: admin

Is there a way to toggle the left/sidebar admin menu altogether, like VSCode or SublimeText?

It'd be great to only display the sections & entries on certain occasions. This comes in handy especially if there are several columns selected in a particular section.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this, but you can build that functionality into a module. This will inject some CSS to all CP requests that will remove the sidebar and make the page container span the entire page:

```php
/** @var craft\web\View $view */
$view = Craft::$app->getView();

if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsCpRequest()) {
    $view->registerCss(<<<'CSS'
        #global-sidebar {
            display: none;
        }
        body.ltr #page-container {
            padding-left: 0;
        }
        #main-content {
            width: 100vw;
        }
    CSS);
}
```

(Will need some adjustments if you need to support `rtl` languages.)

Now this alone is not particularly useful, but you can make it more dynamic depending on your requirements:

- To limit this to particular user groups, you can use the [**Control Panel Body Classes** plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/cp-body-classes) and scope the CSS to a particular user group class.
- If you want to have an on/off toggle, you can inject some JavaScript ([see `View::registerJs`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-view#registerJs()-detail)) that adds a floating button to toggle the above CSS on click.

Comment: That sounds good. I think I can get away with injecting CSS or simply using the plugin you suggested.

Much appreciate the reply!

Comment: @JaeBarclay If this solved your issue, would you mind marking my answer as accepted? Thanks.